# Pentaho data integration - Replace in String (deleting everthing after a simbol)

Tags: replace, pdi, step

I´m new on Pentaho and in one of my fields, I have to delete everything after the first " simbol, just like the example:

CTe35210915180327000160570050000752951251590035" versao="3.00"

I´m trying to use the replace in string using RegEx, but I´m not sure how... anyone can help me?

Best regards,
Ana

Answer (score 0):

You can use step "Modified JavaScript value" and using one simple line [Yourstring.match(/[^"]*/i)[0]] you can do this.

You can look this [Transformation](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z5CWxgUUtA3ITwhkgclQme4HX4MBYkG9?usp=sharing).